# (OLS) Two-way interaction significant but turns marginally significant using robust standard errors

Tags: least-squares, interaction, heteroscedasticity, robust-standard-error

I'm using American National Election Studies'(N=4,219) time series (Sept 2016-Jan 2017) data. I tested a theoretically supported interaction in a fully specified OLS model, which proved to be significantly positive (t=2.12; p=0.034). To correct for heteroskedasticity, I ran the model a second time using robust standard errors. This time, the predicted interaction was only 'marginally' significant (t=1.84; p=0.065). I'm not sure how to go about interpreting this when writing up the results. Should I report the average marginal effects or just conclude that the interaction was insignificant (or 'marginally significant')?

Comment: Just one of many reasons to be frustrated with the absolute standard of $\alpha=.05$. I would make sure that you have appropriately checked all assumptions and examined the possibility of influential cases in your model. If the robust standard error approach still doesn't yield a significant result, I would recommend interpreting the interaction as not significant.

Comment: If you have heteroskedasticity, your normal standard errors will be be too small, so the loss of significance is appropriate. However, you also need to worry about autocorrelation with time series data, so robust errors are not sufficient. You might consider fitting something that can also deal with that.